# C# Random list that adjusts for enabled or disabled items

Tags: c#, arrays, list, random

I am building a random roll program, I'd like it to select an item based on a number associated with it. However, I need to be able to enable or disable some of these items and adjust the roll for that new total while still maintaining a random selection. Asking for the world right?

I already have the code for the roll, and I have searched all over, but cannot find anything like an example of how to make the list so I can enable or disable items and still roll to randomly select an item from the now adjusted list.

Anyone have an idea what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all of the "valid" items into a list and generate a random index for that list, rather than using the random number generator to generate the actual value itself.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example? I'm a visual learner, and while what I think will work, I'd just like to see if I have it correct.

BTW thank you, I never thought of this, and it does sound simple compared to what I had thought up.

Comment: @ParagonUltima What about this are you struggling with?  Do you not know how to put the items into a list?  Do you not know how to get a random index of a list?  If you have an implementation of this solution and it's not working then show what you're doing and explain why it's not working.

Comment: I've only just started learning to code, the one I created uses if, else if and else to print out the result of a random.range. It's a very simple code, but I learn by seeing an example then trial and error.

Comment: You haven't answered any of my questions.  If you want help, you're going to have to explain what you don't understand, and what problem(s) you're having.  You don't need to explain to me why you don't understand something, you just need to tell me what you don't understand.

Comment: How to make a list and how to pull its index. To cover it as well how to validate.

Comment: @ParagonUltima Sounds like you should look at the documentation for `List<T>`.  It will show you lots of examples on how to create a list, as well as how to get/set items at a given index.